# keyof typeof const

Tags: typescript, autocomplete

I have the following TypeScript code:

```js
type Rule = Record<
    string, 
    () => Promise<void>
>;

const rules: Rule = {
    'Belgium': async () => {

    }
} as const;

type RuleName = keyof typeof rules;

type Variant = {
    customer: {
        crmId: string,
        name: string,
    },
    rules: RuleName[],
};

const variants: Variant[] = [
    {
        customer: {
            crmId: 'NL21040010',
            name: 'ACME',
        },
        rules: [ 'Belgium' ],
    },
    {
        customer: {
            crmId: 'BE13120059',
            name: 'John Doe Inc.',
        },
        rules: [ 'Belgium']
    }
];
```

I would like auto completion in VS Code for rule names inside the variants array child objects.
At the same time, I also want the rules to conform to the Rule type.

I could have the type RuleName to equal 'Belgium' instead of 'string' (what I want) with the following code:

```js
const rules = {
    'Belgium': async () => {

    }
} as const;
```

This gives me autocompletion.
But I would like to make use of the Rule type as well.

```js
const rules: Rule = {
    'Belgium': async () => {

    }
} as const;
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: `as const satisfies Rule` probably… will make sure when I’m off mobile.

Comment: Okay, great. See the linked q/a for more information.